# How to get to the prompt window for network username and password

Tags: vbscript, nas

I am writing a VB script to automatically mount a network drive for a network location hosted by our Synology NAS DS218j device (if that's important) at each computer start-up. I also want users to enter their username and password if they are prompted by the NAS device. The problem is, that the NAS user profiles may differ from those for Windows 10, so each user has to enter its username and password when connecting to the NAS device location (also while mounting network drives) for the first time:

[image: NAS Device prompt-window]

After the first successful log in the credentials can be saved.

The problems is:
How to get to this prompt window from VBScript? What I tried to do already is:

Simply to mount the drive: I get an error, that the username and password are invalid (clear, because it uses the windows profile password):

```
Dim objNetwork 
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
strDriveLetter = "T:" 
strRemotePath = "\\192.168.2.247\BlaBla"
objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive strDriveLetter, strRemotePath
```

To catch the error and tell the explorer to open the window (to imitate the behaviour, what user does manually to get the NAS login window open):

```
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    WScript.Echo CStr(Err.Description)
    If Err.Number = CLng("&H" & 80070056) Then
        On Error Goto 0
        Dim objShell
        Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Dim intReturn
        Dim cmdString
        cmdString = "Explorer.exe /n,/root," + strRemotePath
        intReturn = objShell.Run(cmdString, 1, True)
    Else
        WScript.Quit
    End If
End If
```

What that actually does is opening the "Documents" folder! It also does not wait for the window to get closed (what I actually expected to be done, by giving the third argument `True` to `objShell.Run` command.

I have considered a solution through the IE-based custom dialogbox to prompt users for their passwords, but the problem with thit approach is, that in this case, users have to enter their username and password each time they start/restart his/her PC (no save option). The Dialog, which Windows presents, allows the users to save their password for the next time.

Saving user passwords, which I collect from that custom dialog-box is not the solution I am seeking for, because then I have the security issue.

Any ideas how to get to this login window through VBScript commands?

Answer (score 2):

Do not try to automate the password dialog Windows is presenting you with. Instead pass the credentials via the respective parameters of the [`MapNetworkDrive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//8kst88h6%28v%3dvs.85%29) method:

```
username = "..."
password = "..."
...
objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive strDriveLetter, strRemotePath, False, username, password
```

If you need to prompt the user for their credentials (that wasn't clear to me from your question) the simplest way would be using `InputBox` dialogs. However, since you can't hide the password input in those you may want to create a [custom dialog](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_ui_password.php#InternetExplorer) instead. Something like this:

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

ie.Navigate "about:blank"
ie.Document.title = "Title"
ie.ToolBar        = False
ie.Resizable      = False
ie.StatusBar      = False
ie.Width          = 320
ie.Height         = 180

While ie.ReadyState <> 4 : WScript.Sleep 100 : Wend

ie.Document.body.innerHTML = _
  "<p><input type='text' size='20' id='Username'></p>" & vbNewLine & _
  "<p><input type='password' size='20' id='Password'></p>" & vbNewLine & _
  "<p><input type='hidden' id='OK' name='OK' value='0'>" & _
  "<input type='submit' value='Foo' onClick='VBScript:OK.value=1'></p>"
ie.Document.body.style.overflow = "auto"

ie.Visible = True
ie.Document.all.Username.focus

On Error Resume Next
Do While ie.Document.all.OK.value = 0
  WScript.Sleep 100
Loop
On Error Goto 0

username = objIE.Document.all.Username.value
password = objIE.Document.all.Password.value
```

Comment: 1. Because passwords have to be kept secret and only known to the user (I wont know the password of each user, he/she has to enter it themselves)
2. Because the script has to be versatile work for each user (no predefined data, which is supposed to be variable)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have considered this way already (also through the IE based custom dialogbox), but the problem with this approach is, that in this case, the users have to enter their username and password each time they start/restart his/her PC (no save option). 

The Dialog, which Windows presents, allows the users to save their password for the next time. That's why I want to get that dialog. You will probably recommend me to save user passwords, which I collect from that custom dialog-box, but then I have a security issue! 

Any other solution?

Comment: @Vytautas did you mention any of this in the original question, do you not think that would have been relevant to those trying to help you?

Comment: @Lankymart thank you for your precise comment. Already expanded my initial question.

Comment: So, I guess, since you realized that's not some simple case, there is no solutions to that... :/